# Vayimaen (וימאן) Connection

Tags: words, pentateuch-chumash, genesis-bereishith

The word וימאן is mentioned 3 times in Sefer Bereishis

- Where Yaakov refuses to be consoled over the supposed death of Yosef [(37:35)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.37.35?lang=bi)
- Where Yosef refuses the advancement of Eishes Potifar [(39:8)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.39.8?lang=bi)
- Where Yaakov refuses to switch his hands' position on Ephraim and Menashe [(48:19)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.48.19?lang=bi)

Much has been said about each individual וימאן, but is there a connection between these 3 incidents (more than simply involving Yaakov and Yosef), which could explain why they all use this specific word?